# Batch reg query key to variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, prompt

When I run the command `REG Query HKLM /k /F "Command Processor" /s /e /c` on `cmd`, I get this result:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Command Processor`

End results: 2 match(s) found(s).

But in batch:

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('REG Query HKLM /k /F "Command Processor" /s /e /c') do set "MyPath=%%a"
echo The path string value is "%MyPath%"
pause
```

When I execute this, I only get the last line:

The path string value is "End results: 2 match(s) found(s)."

What is wrong? I would like to get the path keys on variables.

Comment: To get only the first path break out of the loop after setting the path with `goto done` and `:done` label on the line after the loop.

Comment: This works for first line, but I need the 2nd line too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is obvious: you are overwriting the value of `MyPath` in the `for /F` loop, then you are printing (`echo`) the *final* value/line.

To get *all* lines (any arbitrary number) you could do the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem storing the path strings in `MyPath1`, `MyPath2`, etc.:
set /A count=0
for /F "delims=" %%A in (
    'REG Query HKLM /K /F "Command Processor" /S /E /C ^
    ^| findstr /L /B /V /C:"End of search: "'
) do (
    set /A count+=1
    set "MyPath!count!=%%A"
)
rem extracting the previously stored path strings:
echo Total number of path strings: %count%
for /L %%B in (1,1,%count%) do (
    echo The !count!. path string value is "!MyPath%%B!"
)
pause
endlocal
```

This constitutes a sort of array `MaPath1`, `MyPath2`, and so on, containing all matching path strings.

The `findstr` command is used to filter out the summary line `End of search:` (this might be adapted according to your system locale/language).

Note that the array is no longer available after the `endlocal` command.

Comment: Works perfect for two instances. But if exists n lines in registry, how I get the results for (n-1) lines? I don't want the last line "End results:...."